# I would like to ask about the orthogonality between null space and column space

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:Let $A$ be a (possibly rectangular) matrix. Show that $A^TAx = b$ has a solution
if and only if $b$ is orthogonal to $Null(A)$.

My troubles about this question:

First thing is about b, I have no idea about how to represent it in the form of subspaces, is it $col(ATA)$?

Second thing is about the orthogonal, I undertand that $Null(A)$ is about $Ax=0$, but what it has to do with b?

Update:I worked to find $Null(A)=Null(A^TA)$, that says $A^TAx=0$, I just need an idea about what to do with b...what null space has to do with column space?

Comment: $b\perp null(A)$ means $b\in (im A^T) = im A^TA$.

Comment: what does that "im" mean?

Comment: The image of $A$, i.e., the space generated by the columns of $A$.

Comment: In your title: $A^TAx=A^2x$ is not true. Give that $A$ can be rectangular, $A^2$ might not even be defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the relevant identities that you should have written down in your notes:

1. $\operatorname{Row}(A) \perp \operatorname{Null}(A)$ and hence $\operatorname{Col}(A) = \operatorname{Row}(A^\top) \perp \operatorname{Null}(A^\top)$

because to compute $Ax$ you take the dot product of $x$ with each row of $A$. If these are all $0$ then $x$ is orthogonal to each row of $A$ and hence to any linear combination of rows (the row space).

2. If $A^\top Ax = 0$ then $x^\top A^\top Ax = 0$ and hence $\lVert Ax \rVert^2 = 0$ and hence $Ax = 0$.

it follows then (you can finish the proof) that $\operatorname{Null}(A^\top A) = \operatorname{Null}(A)$.

3. If $U, W_1, W_2$ are subspaces (nullspaces/column spaces/whatever) such that $U \perp W_1$ and $U \perp W_2$ then $W_1 = W_2$. We write $U^\perp$ for the unique subspace $W$ such that $U \perp W$.
4. $\operatorname{Null}(A) = \operatorname{Null}((A^\top)^\top) \perp \operatorname{Col}(A^\top)$ (by the second part of 1.)

The identity in 1. has a couple ways of writing it by putting transposes in various places.

5. other definitions/identities:

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Null}(A) &= \{x : Ax = 0\} \\
\operatorname{Col}(A) &= \operatorname{Span}\{\text{columns of } A\} &\text{(also called the image or range of $A$)} \\
&= \{y : y = Ax \text{ for some $x$}\} \\
&= \{y : y = Ax \text{ has a solution}\} &\text{(synonym: is consistent)} \\
&= \{Ax : x \in \text{the domain}\} \\
\operatorname{Row}(A) &= \operatorname{Span}\{\text{rows of } A\} = \operatorname{Col}(A^\top) \\
x \perp y &\iff x \cdot y = 0 \\
U^\perp &= \{x : x \perp y \text{ for all } y \in U\} \\
&= \{x : x \cdot y = 0 \text{ for all } y \in U\} \\
(U^\perp)^\perp &= U
\end{align}

Orthogonality can be challenging but if you take good notes and review the key facts it will be easier.